# Sum values in columns with variable number of Columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a 'Item Demand' table which have 3 different things:

A column with part number of an object, several columns with Dates as titles, and quantities as values in them.

```
Part Number |  Date1 |    Date2 | Date3  |    Date4 ... | Lead Time

2003032.........201.........63.......54..........63.............3  

2145631..........54.........21........53..........21............2

4563214.........23..........121.......12.........31.............5
```

But here's what I need to do and I have no clue how.

So if Lead Time is 3 months, I need to take today's date and sum 3 months, than select the column which correspond to the result of this sum (Only the same month not the same date), than take the value in this column and all the columns before it and sum all.

I'm not sure if I have made my self clear, I'm sorry if I did not. I'll try to explain further if there are any questions.

Hope someone could help.

Excel 2002

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What have you tried so far?  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on asking questions that are likely to elicit effective answers.

Comment: Use an array formula for this or sumif

Comment: I need this in vba, ive done a macro so far that takes information from SAP, and analizes some data, but im depending on this to go on.

Comment: what I tough i could do was add value of column 'lead time' to todays date. That would give me the last column I want. But than I dont know how to make vba know what column this is, and then sum this column and all the values till the first column.

so...
DataLead = Date + Range("AX3").Value

Than that would give me de date wich would be the last column, than I'd have to find a similar date in the date columns (to find the same mothn). That would give me a column, I than have to some how select this column and select all the way to the fist column, and sum all values inside.

Comment: Once you have the answer - what cell does it go in?

Comment: Also, in your example data, all the months are in the past - so you'd never get a match. If today is 12th July then +3 months is 12th October - therefore no match. Is that intended?

Comment: I just put a random date actualy, in my table I have 3 years of dates, and the final result goes to a diferrent sheet

Answer (score 0):

Fim. You don't need VBA for your situation, the formulas SUM and OFFSET should do. I made a very simple sheet to make it clear:

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8oi1.png)

Comment: I think that would help, im going to try it out. But i your table why are 3 diferent dates for "TODAY DATE'

Comment: It's an imput to test if the formula would be OK with variable dates. You can change the values in that column for =TODAY() .

Answer (score 0):

assuming

- dates are in ascending order from left to right
- dates are in contiguous range (no blanks between them)
- dates are the only numbers in their row
- leadtimes are the only numbers in their column

then you can try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, datesRng As Range
    Dim jMonth As Variant
    Dim mySht As Worksheet: Set mySht = Worksheets("leadtimes") '<--| change "leadtimes" with your actual sheet name
    Dim leadCol As String: leadCol = "N" '<--| change "N" to your actual lead times column index

    With mySht
        Set datesRng = .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        For Each cell In .Columns(leadCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            jMonth = Application.Match(CLng(DateAdd("m", cell.Value, Date)), datesRng, 1)
            If Not IsError(jMonth) Then cell.offset(, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(datesRng.offset(cell.Row - datesRng.Rows(1).Row).Resize(, jMonth))
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @L.Fim: did you try this?